Using OpenJson in select statement
If I have a database table with (details being a JSON string):
Id   Details                            Price
----------------------------------------------
1   {"partNumber":"012345","qty":14}    14.99
2   {"partNumber":"22222","qty":11}      4.88
3   {"partNumber":"44444","qty":1}       3.24
4   {"partNumber":"72431223","qty":9}    3.33
5   {"partNumber":"98989","qty":1}       3.33

I only want to return partNumber and price.
So for example
SELECT
    Details.partNumber, Price 
FROM
    tableName 
WHERE
    price < 10.00

I've been playing about with this and so far have
SELECT
    Details.partNumber, price 
FROM
    tableName (SELECT partNumber  
               FROM OPENJSON(tableName.Details)) 
WHERE
    Price = 10.00

which doesn't work. Any help would be great. Thanks for any replies

@VLOOKUP why would you care about the version of ssms? Surely you only care about the version of SQL server?

@VLOOKUP there are already enough people confused by the difference between ssms and SQL server without making it worse.

You can use the JSON_VALUE function to extract a single piece of data from a JSON structure in a column.
Change your code to look like this:
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.partNumber') AS 'PartNumber', 
    price 
FROM
    tableName 
WHERE
    Price < 10.00


I went with this answer thanks for the reply and the help

SELECT 
    part.value AS partNumber,
    t.Price
FROM 
    tableName t
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(t.Details) 
    WITH (partNumber nvarchar(255) '$.partNumber') AS part
WHERE 
    t.Price = 10.00;


A good answer contains an explanation in addition to a working query.

thanks for taking the time to respond
